# SharePoint 2013 Top Navigation Snippet Not Showing Publishing Pages

Tags: 2013, custom-masterpage, branding, sharepont

I am developing custom SharePoint MasterPage page.

The issue is that Top Navigation snippet does not show publishing pages links in my custom MasterPage whereas default Seattle master page does shows it.

Take a look at Navigation Settings, also notice Pages are listed on top navigation by  default Master page:
[image]

Custom Master page, shows only two items and does not include publishing pages:
[image]

Top Navigation do shows pages in preview mode:
[image]

Comment: Check if your SiteMapProvider in your custom master page is "SPNavigationProvider" or not. Are the pages published?

Comment: Yes it was SPNavigationProvider. Now I realized pages need to be published to to appear in navigation, event it applies to Admin. Thanks for pointing. Please propose your answer as solution and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page needs to be published to show up in the navigation.

P.S: Sometimes, undo(ing) and redo(ing) the Show pages checkbox also makes it work.

Comment: In my case the page was newly created and never checked in or published. So I guess at least one published version is required to appear in navigation.

Comment: I Published the pages. However still not showing. Am i missing some thing. Mine too is a custom master page.